# SQL Compare list of string values with table without writing to database and retrieve rest of list

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, comparison

I have a comma separated list with a lot of values(strings) and I want to compare it to a MS SQL Server 2008 table. I am trying to get which of the values in the list that are not in the table. I don't want to write to the database at all if possible.

I have found this previous post that is similar to my question but I can't quite figure out how to make it work with strings.

[Comparing list of values against table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872307/comparing-list-of-values-against-table)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To follow up on this. The closest thing I could find to a solution is to manually enter the comma separated values by first formatting all rows then running it something like this:

```
DECLARE @TempTable table(firstcol varchar(50))
INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES ('mystring1')
INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES ('mystring2')
INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES ('mystring3')
INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES ('mystring4')
...
SELECT * FROM @TempTable WHERE firstcol NOT IN (SELECT tablecol FROM [MyTable])
```

It seems that if I have a greater version (2012?) I would also be able to do this:

```
INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES('mystring1'),('mystring2'),('mystring3')
```

The closest other alternatives I could find though still writing to database would be:

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
GO

select TerritoryID
      ,TotalSales
      ,TotalCost
INTO CSVImportTable
from openrowset('MSDASQL'
               ,'Driver={Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)}'
               ,'select * from C:\csvtest.CSV')
```

Found here: [How to create and populate a table in a single step as part of a CSV import operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418461/how-to-create-and-populate-a-table-in-a-single-step-as-part-of-a-csv-import-oper)

And this alternative with a temporary table:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable (FName nvarchar(max),SName nvarchar(max),
                          Email nvarchar(max));
BULK INSERT #TempTable 
FROM 'C:\52BB30AD694A62A03E.csv' 
WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')
```

Found here: [Whats wrong with this SQL statement for table variable bulk insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113820/whats-wrong-with-this-sql-statement-for-table-variable-bulk-insert)