# Django: Find an item in a list that is not in Database

Tags: python, django

I have a list and I want to find whether any items in this list are not in the database.

Using the `object.exclude()` Django function I only find which elements are in my database that are not in my list:

```
Gene.objects.exclude(gene_name__in=self.gene_list)
```

I am currently getting the items I have in my list that aren't in the database using this code:

```
obj = Gene.objects.filter(gene_name__in=self.gene_list)
database_genes = [o.gene_name for o in obj]
genes_not_in_db =  [g for g in self.gene_list if g not in database_genes]
```

This is however rather messy - is there a better way / inbuilt Django function to do this?
Thanks

Comment: I was going to say the same as iklinac, but when I was looking around I saw [a solution using the DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872307/comparing-list-of-values-against-table), and I suppose you could do that with Django's [difference method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#difference), if you were willing to load the gene names into a temporary table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your way of dealing with is just what needs to be done but rather than using expensive array you should use sets/dict

```
genes = Gene.objects.filter(gene_name__in=self.gene_list).values('gene_name')
genes_set = set(gene.gene_name for gene in genes)
not_in_db = set(gene_list) - genes_set
```